# Passing a data class through multiple components

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm not really sure how to describe my issue here, but here goes-

I'm building an RPG Bot for people to interact with, so I have a Quest class that is given all of the information about the current game. It contains players, what path to take, etc. I then have components, for example a Beginning component and an Ending component, with various components in between. I'd like to execute each component one by one, with them all having the Quest class so as to allow each component to modify data as it needs.

For example, in Pseudocode:

```
export default class Quest {
    constructor(gameID) {
        this.gameID = gameID;
        this.players = new Map();
    }
    //Getters/Setters etc.
}

class BeginningComponent {
    constructor(quest) {
         this.quest = quest;
    }

    run() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
             killPlayer();
             resolve()
        })
    }
}
```

And then, to run them;

```
const run = async () => {
     await new BeginningComponent(quest).run();
     await new SecondComponent(quest).run();
     await new EndingComponent(quest).run();
}
```

So.. It works. But it doesn't seem effective at all. I'm having difficulty with 'thinking' how to structure this.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like go in OOP style you can define base class Component and extend it by your BeginningComponent, SecondComponent, etc components. In this case you could create run function like

```
const run = async (components) => {
    for (component of components) {
        await component.run()
    }
}
```

define components list in quest  and add component there each time you create new component

```
class Quest {

    constructor(gameID) {
        this.gameID = gameID;
        this.players = new Map();
    }

    registerComponent (component) {
        this.components.push(components)
    }

    async run (components) {
        for (component of this.components) {
            await component.run()
        }
    }
}

class Component {
    constructor(quest) {
         this.quest = quest;
         this.quest.registerComponent(this)
    }
    run() {}
}
```

Also i would like to recommend you typescript for OOP code. It could help you when you project will be bigger